# TS1005 and TS1002 in first string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I read about these warnings but I did not manage to solve the problem.
VS have last update.

TS1002 (JS) ',' expected.
TS1005 (JS) Unterminated string literal.
TS1002 (JS) ',' expected.
TS1005 (JS) Unterminated string literal.

these warnings were written 2x twice as I wrote (I don't understand what it means)

file type - ViewAll.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebSQLserver.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewAll";
    Layout = null;
}


<table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="employeeTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Position)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Office)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Office)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="Edit('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit", "Employee", new { id=@item.EmployeeID})')"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="Delete('@Url.Action("Delete", "Employee", new { id=@item.EmployeeID})')"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

file type Controller.cs

```
namespace WebSQLserver.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewAll()
        {
            return View(GetAllEmployee());
        }

        IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            using(DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                return db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Those are typescript error codes, but you have no TypeScript code in your question.

Comment: I corrected the post, help understand that with first line is wrong

Comment: You say you "corrected the post" but you didn't actually address Amy's point. The error you're describing for TypeScript, yet you've shown no TypeScript code in your question. How do you think we're going to be able to help you? Please read over [MCVE].

Comment: I've got a lot this kind of alert with Javascript only code, not with TypeScript. I was never able to isolate the cause, it comes and goes...